# i am creating a post method in django and written a def in vie but it is not printing in consele. i think prog is not able to get in IF condition

Tags: django

```
def post1(request):
    form = EmployeeForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            eid = form.cleaned_data['eid']
            ename = form.cleaned_data['ename']
            ecity = form.cleaned_data['ecity']
            employer = form.cleaned_data['employer']
            print(eid, ename, ecity, employer)## it is not printing on the cnsole.
    return render(request, "app1/post1.html", {'form' : form})
```

Is there any mistake.this is the post method i am creating and there is a employee form and what i want if i filll data in the field it will show in the command prompt.

Comment: You've already worked out that the `if` condition isn't firing - so then question is why. That condition wouldn't fire if the form isn't valid - so this is where you need to look next. If you render `form.errors` in your template (or inspect it in the view) it will tell you why the form was invalid.

Comment: Show your form.